# How to add new column to output file in Python?

Tags: python, file, fwrite

I have this code written in Python. How can I add a new column "qty" that contains the number "1" at each row?

This is the file `tripo`:

```
{
'1.txt': [], 
'2.txt': [], 
'5.txt': [], 
'4.txt': ['3.txt','6.txt'],
'7.txt': ['8.txt']
}
```

This is the code:

```
with open("test.csv","wa") as f:
    f.write("num\n")
    for k, v in tripo.items():
        if v:
            f.write("{}\n".format(k.split(".")[0]))
            f.write("\n".join([s.split(".")[0] for s in v])+"\n
```

Expected output (the given code creates a second column, while I want to add column "name"):

```
name num
1  4
1  3
1  6
1  7
1  8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you're writing the name column to your file. It could be done as:

```
with open("test.csv","wa") as f:
    f.write("name\tnum\n")
    for k, v in tripo.items():
        if v:
            f.write("1\t")
            f.write("{}\n".format(k.split('.')[0]))
            for s in v:
                f.write("1\t{}\n".format(s.split('.')[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please put the code that you just deleted, where you created the list.

Comment: @klausos It should be available in the answer's edit history.

Comment: I think there is some issue with your code, because "1" does not appear in the first column for all entries. Could you please fix this?

Comment: This line can generate multiple entries. How can I add "1" in the first column for these entries? f.write("\n".join([s.split(".")[0] for s in v])+"\n")

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Thanks for pointing that out. It is because of the nature of join method. You can iterate over the list to add those entries. I've modified the code as such.