# How to save two-column array in a file in Python

Tags: python, file, fwrite

I have this code (see [this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941924/how-to-add-new-column-to-output-file-in-python/28943241?noredirect=1#comment46142245_28943241)) for saving a two-column array in the file. The thing is that I need to call this function N times:

```
   def save(self):
        n=self.n
        with open("test.csv","a") as f:
            f.write("name\tnum\n")
            for k, v in tripo.items():
                if v:
                    f.write(n+"\t")
                    f.write("{}\n".format(k.split(".")[0]))
                    for s in v:
                        f.write(n+"\t")
                        f.write("\n".join([s.split(".")[0]])+"\n")
```

This is the sample content of `tripo` for n=1:

```
{
'1.txt': [], 
'2.txt': [], 
'5.txt': [], 
'4.txt': ['3.txt','6.txt'],
'7.txt': ['8.txt']
}
```

This is the expected output for n=1...N:

```
name num
1  4
1  3
1  6
1  7
1  8
...
N 3
N 6
N ...
```

However, the above-given code puts some values in the same column.

UPDATE:
For instance, if I have this string `'170.txt': ['46.txt','58.txt','86.txt']`, then I receive this result:

```
1   1   1   1   170
46
58
86
```

instead of:

```
1  170
1  46
1  58
1  86
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

tripo = [
('1.txt', []), 
('2.txt', []), 
('5.txt', []), 
('4.txt', ['3.txt','6.txt']),
('7.txt', ['8.txt'])
]

def getname(f):
    return os.path.splitext(f)[0]

def getresult(t):
    result = []
    for k, v in tripo:
        values = [getname(n) for n in v]
        if len(values)>0:
            result.append(getname(k))
        for x in values:
            result.append(x)
    return result

def writedown(n,r):
    with open("test.csv","a") as f:
        for x in r:
            f.write("%s\t%s\n" % (n,x))
            print("%s\t%s\n" % (n,x))

print(getresult(tripo))

writedown(1, getresult(tripo))
```

Comment: I have used tripo as a list of tuples for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Pickle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle). Use pickle.dump to store to file and pickle.load to load it.

Comment: Could you give some concrete example for my case?

Comment: I don't understand quite well your question. Does the object representation is correct but the writing in the file incorrect? If this is the case, using pickle could be useful.  Try,   import pickle

Comment: yes,writing in the file is not correct

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand quite well your question.

Does the object representation is correct but the writing in the file incorrect?

If this is the case as Dan said, using pickle could be useful.

```
import pickle;

s = pickle.dumps(object); 
f.write(s); 
f.close(); 

#for reading; 
f = open('test.csv', 'rb');
serialized_object = pickle.load(f)
```

The `serialized_object`variable should have the structure you want to preserve.